# How do I bind a model automatically in background without change action parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have coded a model binder to return a simple model. I want to bind this model to every controllers without change any controller action parameters. Is there anyway to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A model binder is usually associated to a given type. So in your `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(SomeViewModel), new SomeModelBinder());
```

This will register the `SomeModelBinder` model binder to all controller actions which take a `SomeViewModel` as parameter. For example:

```
public ActionResult Foo(SomeViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```